# How to move static members between classes in Roslyn? (C#)

Tags: c#, obfuscation, roslyn

As a small step in part of a larger obfuscation process, I'd like to move all static members in the project into one class and update references accordingly.

I'm aware that on its own, this kind of obfuscation isn't very strong but it's only one step of a larger process and also partly a learning exercise.

I'm also aware that this will impact code quality but it will only be a step in a build process and the results won't be committed.

I've gotten part way which I will share below:

```
    public async Task Run(string solutionPath)
    {
        // Create a workspace to allow loading our solution
        m_workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

        // Load our target solution
        Solution solution = await m_workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);

        // Find all projects in the solution
        var projects = solution.Projects;

        // Get the first project
        var project = projects.FirstOrDefault();

        // Enumerate through documents in the project
        foreach (var document in project.Documents)
        {
            // Get our syntax tree representation of the document
            var syntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
            var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();

            // Find all classes and pass them to be renamed
            var classes = syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
            foreach (var c in classes)
            {
                foreach (var member in c.Members)
                {
                    if (//How to check if the member is static?)
                    {
                        var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(member).Symbol;
                        var references = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(symbol, solution);
                        //How to move the member to another class and update the references?
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // When completed, apply changes to our solution
        m_workspace.TryApplyChanges(solution);
    }
```

This mostly was derived from here: https://blog.xpnsec.com/building-modifying-packing-devops/

- How can I check if a member is static or not in Roslyn?
- How can I move the member to another class and update the references?

Comment: I can't help with the second part, but `BindingFlags.Static` should help you with the first.

Comment: @ClickRick it will not help in case of working with Roslyn API's =)